# Does SQLite have something like insert_id?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a c# project that uses sqlite and I wonder if there is something like the mysql_insert_id method as in php ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQLite3 `SELECT last_insert_rowid()` should work, as explained here: [how to get last inserted Id of a Sqlite database using Zend_Db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506132/how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-sqlite-database-using-zend-db)

Answer (score 1):

The SQLite base API (in C) has [`sqlite3_last_insert_rowid`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) which looks ideal for this sort of thing. It's also available at the SQL level via the [`last_insert_rowid()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) function. I don't know how this maps to C#, but that should help you when looking.