# How get the Id of inserted row in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert

My database table has ID column which is an auto incremental integer. While inserting data to the table its increment automatically I need to get the value of ID when a record is inserted.

Eg: table employee = |ID| NAME | ADDRESS|

the query is :

> `insert into employee(NAME, ADDRESS) values("azzi", "test adress")`

there is a possible that we can change this query to return the ID soon after record inserted, some one help me to do that.

Comment: Your question may already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892973/how-to-get-last-insert-id-in-sqlite .. Please check the link.^_^

Answer (score 7):

With the SQLite [last_insert_rowid()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) function:

> The last_insert_rowid() function returns the ROWID of the last row insert from the database connection which invoked the function.

Answer (score 2):

### SQLite

This is available using the [SQLite `last_insert_rowid()` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid):

> The last_insert_rowid() function returns the ROWID of the last row
>   insert from the database connection which invoked the function. The
>   last_insert_rowid() SQL function is a wrapper around the
>   sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() C/C++ interface function.

Resources : [How to get last insert Id in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892973/how-to-get-last-insert-id-in-sqlite/8893008#8893008)